# How to increase the memory for pandoc via an RMD file?

Tags: r, yaml, pandoc

I'm having a problem with memory allocation when using pandoc ! here's the error I get

```
 output file: rapport_.knit.md

/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS rapport_.knit.md --to docx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output /app/rapport_.docx --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --highlight-style tango --reference-doc tmplt.docx
Killed
<simpleError: pandoc document conversion failed with error 137>
```

after researching, I found a few posts where the solution proposed was using pandoc_args like here https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/315 and here https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-August/431647.html

so I did :

```
---
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), 'Version du %d %B %Y', locale = 'fr_FR')`"
title: "Rapport"
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    toc: TRUE
    pandoc_args: [
      "+RTS", "-K64m",
      "-RTS"
    ]

---
```

when calling my Rmd file using rmarkdwon::render

```
rmarkdown::render("rapport_.Rmd")
```

nothing actually changes, i still get +RTS -K512m -RTS although it's supposed to be "-K64m" now!

any idea how to do that?

Comment: `pandoc_args` are in addition to the default args, and later ones generally override earlier ones.  But 64m is smaller than 512m, so if memory is the issue, you need a bigger number.

Comment: that still doesn't work

Comment: Show us the error message when you do that.

Comment: Even better: show us a reproducible example.  Cut out everything from your document except the part that triggers the error, and show us what's left.